# How to stop my html presentation at the last slide?

Tags: javascript

I'm making a html presentation. It had 15 slides. I have it all working but when I get to the last slide you can continue pressing the left arrow key(the key press that goes to the next slide) to go to slides that I'm not using or even expecting to be there. How can I stop the transition from slide to slide at the last slide.

this is all my javascript

```
var Slides = {
    currentSlide: 0,
    totalSlides: '',
    slideWidth: '',
    translateAmount: 0,
    container: $("#slides"),

    init: function(totalSlides) {
        var each;

        if(!totalSlides) throw new Error('Please pass the number of slides');
        Slides.totalSlides = totalSlides;
        Slides.loadContent();
        each = Slides.container.children('div');
        Slides.slideWidth = each.width() + (parseInt(each.css('margin-right'), 10));
        Slides.keyPress();
    },
    loadContent: function() {
        Slides.container.hide();
        for (var i = 0; i < Slides.totalSlides; i++) {
            $('<div id="#slide-' +i+ '"></div>')
            .load('slides/' +i+ '.html')
            .appendTo(Slides.container);
        }
        Slides.container.show();
    },
    keyPress: function() {
        $(document.body).keydown(function(e) {
            if(e.keyCode === 39 || e.keyCode === 37) {
                e.preventDefault();
                (e.keyCode === 39)?Slides.next():Slides.prev();
            }
        });
    },
    next: function() {
        Slides.translateAmount -= Slides.slideWidth;
        Slides.updateHash(++Slides.currentSlide);
        Slides.animate();
    },
    prev: function() {
        if(Slides.translateAmount === 0) return;

        Slides.translateAmount += Slides.slideWidth;
        Slides.updateHash(--Slides.currentSlide);
        Slides.animate();
    },
    animate: function() {
        Slides.container
            .children()
                .css('-webkit-transform', 'translateX(' +Slides.translateAmount+ 'px)');

    },
    updateHash: function() {
        location.hash = '#slide-' +Slides.currentSlide;
    }
}

Slides.init(15);
```

Comment: You've written `Slides`. Just add a check for the "last" slide.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check if `currentSlide` is equal to 14 (assuming slides start from 0). If its true, just return from the `next` function

```
next: function() {
    if (currentSlide === 14)   
        return;

    Slides.translateAmount -= Slides.slideWidth;
    Slides.updateHash(++Slides.currentSlide);
    Slides.animate();
}
```

Comment: Okay that makes sense. Just for reference I had to enter the Slides object before calling current slide so the code looked like `next: function() {
        if (Slides.currentSlide === 14) return;
        Slides.translateAmount -= Slides.slideWidth;
        Slides.updateHash(++Slides.currentSlide);
        Slides.animate();
    },`